# Improve axios get download speed

Tags: reactjs, axios, azure-blob-storage

I am using `axios` to download a file (~100MB) from an Azure Storage Blob.

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: uri,
  onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
    console.log("Loaded: " + ((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100) + "%"); 
  },
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).then({})
```

My problem is that it is taking quite a while to actually download the file (~10 minutes). I was previously using fetch() which was slower than this even (~15-20 minutes). Are there any recommendations you guys have on how to speed up the download? My internet speed isn't the problem, as downloading the file directly or using the Azure Storage Explorer(1.12.0, AzCopy 10.3.3) takes less than 2 minutes.

I also tried using azure-storage's blobServiceClient, but got similar speeds to axios and fetch (roughly 15kbps).

This is in a React app if that helps.

Comment: Can you provide your uri format ?

Comment: My answer  you can test by yourself , I think it will useful to you, you just need to replace the url for test.

Comment: I am looking forward to your test results, and if my suggestions are effective for you, I'm glad you can tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have test the speed of download. I hope my result can useful to you.

> 1. I upload `StorageExplorer.exe` as source file for download test. The size of file is 92.5M.

[image]

> 2. Download file by `Azure Storage Explore`, it will took `1 minute and 07 seconds`.

[image]

> 3. Download file in portal by chrome broswer, it will took `58 seconds`.

[image]

> 4. Download file by my test code.

**① Copy Url from `portal` or `Storage Explore`.**

[image]

The url like ：`https://p*****ge.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/StorageExplorer.exe`

After test by my code, it will took `1 minute and 52 seconds` and it is very unstable, sometimes the test download time will be longer.

**② Copy Url from `AzCopy Command`.**

The url format look like： `https://pan********ge.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/StorageExplorer.exe?se=2020-09-18T07%3A55%3A28Z&sp=rl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=5kJyTBwHHRS******mlj3%2FWj9CmvQriXCMi4%3D`

After test by same code, it will took `1 minute and 02 seconds`.

> ***My test conclusion:***

Don't use url which look like `https://p*****ge.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/StorageExplorer.exe`.

**You can use url which look like get from AzCopy Command.**

***Below is my test code.***

> 1. npm i progress
> 2. npm i axios

```
'use strict'

const Fs = require('fs')  
const Path = require('path')  
const Axios = require('axios')  
const ProgressBar = require('progress')

async function download () {  
  const url =    'https://pan*****e.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/StorageExplorer.exe'

  console.log('Connecting …')
  const { data, headers } = await Axios({
    url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'stream'
  })
  const totalLength = headers['content-length']

  console.log('Starting download')
  const progressBar = new ProgressBar('-> downloading [:bar] :percent :etas',     {
      width: 40,
      complete: '=',
      incomplete: ' ',
      renderThrottle: 1,
      total: parseInt(totalLength)
    })

  const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(
    Path.resolve(__dirname, 'software', 'StorageExplorer.exe')
  )
  data.on('data', (chunk) => progressBar.tick(chunk.length))
  data.pipe(writer)
}

download()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! Using the AZ Copy url improved my speed to a more reasonable time of <2 minutes for larger files