# Downloading files from blob storage using a deployed Azure function is extremely slow

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

We have been having this issue using Python 3.8 for a long time.

1. Running an Azure function locally via "func start" and downloading files from blob storage is as fast as expected
2. Running a deployed Azure function (via app service plan) results in a download speed of ~50kb/s

What is the issue here?

I expected the deployed function to download blob files even faster than running it locally as they are in the same network?

File size is ~2 MB, using Azure blob storage v12.8.0 and the following code

```
blob_client = service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=file_name)
data = blob_client.download_blob(max_concurrency=4)
return data.readall()
```

Regards
Sebastian

Comment: Pls show your sample code in .py file. It is recommended that you use sas token when downloading.

Comment: Are these 2 services in the same region ?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes both ressources are in same region. A quick test using .NET and an Azure function on consumption plan showed the expected speed. I suspect it has something to do with Azure blob service SDK in Python. We'll try using the SAS Token approach as we're currently using a connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended that you download through the `sas token`, because I tested it when running the nodejs program before and found that the download speed using `sas token` is faster.

*You can read my test steps in below post.*

**[Improve axios get download speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336999/improve-axios-get-download-speed/63482849#63482849)**